# Correct number of decimal places reading in a .csv

Tags: r, csv, decimal

I have a .csv where one of the columns contains numbers that have 7 decimal places, e.g.: `-117.2403266`.

When I'm reading the `.csv` into R it only ever shows 4 decimal places for that column, e.g.: `-117.2403`. Or maybe they are all there but when I print it only shows the four decimal places?

I thought that this might be solved within the arguments of the `read.csv()` function, but it doesn't say anything about decimal places.

Comment: See `options` and the `digits` entry.

Comment: You can also use `format(Data, digits=n)` to check if your data frame is actually getting read correctly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`read.csv` is not truncating or rounding, but your `print.data.frame` function is only displaying the values to the precision specified in `options()`. Try:

```
 print(dfrm, digits=10)

> dfrm<- data.frame(test=-117.2403266)
> print(dfrm)
       test
1 -117.2403
> print(dfrm, digits=10)
          test
1 -117.2403266
```

Using `format` as suggested would show that the precision has not been lost, but  it would return a character vector, so it might not be suitable for assignment when a numeric value was expected.

Edit of a 2 yr-old post: This topic might bring up the question regarding how integers can be imported when they are larger than  `.Machine$integer.max #[1] 2147483647`, since such they can now be internally stored exactly as 'numeric'-abscissa values, so that maximum would be 2^52 (or 2^53-1, I forget which it is). When these are read in from a `scan`-based function (as are all 0f the `read.*`-family), you would need to declare as 'numeric' rather than 'integer':

```
> str( scan(text="21474836470", what=integer()))
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '21474836470'
> str( scan(text="21474836470", what=numeric()))
Read 1 item
 num 2.15e+10
> str( read.table(text="21474836470", colClasses="integer"))
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '21474836470'
> str( read.table(text="21474836470", colClasses="numeric"))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num 2.15e+10
```

If you don't specify a type or mode for "what", `scan` would assume `numeric()` and it would succeed.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I was wondering if it was a problem with the .csv being read in improperly or the printing that was doing it. Thanks for clarifying!